# How are Russians who oppose/distrust their government supposed to live abroad?

Tags: immigration, banking, russia, asylum, russian-citizens

In the last six weeks since Russia's unprovoked and illegal attack against Ukraine, a lot of young Russians have left the country in protest against their government. However, paradoxically, Western sanctions have made their lives more difficult. Their travel options to European countries are now very limited, and even their bank accounts can no longer be accessed nor can they open new bank accounts abroad just because of their citizenship.

An example is the YouTuber [NFKRZ](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC19xLluI7dG093Gmw57BhHw) who fled from Russia to Georgia and is now neither able to open a Georgian bank account nor is he able to withdraw his funds.

What is the best way for Russians to find a life abroad? Are there countries where they can get political asylum?

Comment: Simply being opposed to the actions of their government is not a criteria for claiming asylum. To be granted asylum (to get refugee status), it is necessary to show that you have a well-founded fear of persecution

Comment: Where individual Russians might go will depend upon the visa and immigration laws of the destination. Visa and immigration matters are determined by countries, so there are several hundred possible destinations to be assessed, and then each country's system and requirements must be weighed against each emigrant's interests and desires. All in all, this enquiry is unanswerably broad and will invariably generate opinion and discussion. I voted to close.